# Why is my txt file failing to open in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to open a .txt file that contains integer values 0-9 each individual number on its own line till the last number is 9. When i run the code i'm using im running into an issue with opening my txt file. Based on the if and else statement provided its failing to open what is causing this and what method can i use to open my notepad .txt file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
ifstream infile; //Container for the file
infile.open("assignmentG1.txt"); //Name of the file you want to open
string stringFromFile; //string variables to store extracted strings


if(infile.fail())  {//Display error if the file failed to open
cout<<"Input file failed to open";
}
else
{
getline(infile, stringFromFile);
}
cout<<stringFromFile;
}
```

```
input file failed to open.
```

Comment: You’re openning an input stream but you want to write into a file. Change it to ofstream

Comment: How are you running this program, exactly? Where is the text file located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code works as expected, just make sure you execute the compiled program from the directory where the text file exists.

Assuming the source code is added to a file named `main.cpp` and running on Linux or macOS with gcc compiler installed, the following works:

```
echo "Hello" > assignmentG1.txt
g++ main.cpp -o main
./main
Hello
```

Comment: Im running windows, but the intention of the program is to open the txt file then read each line with a for loop and cout the txt data onto the compiler. I'm stuck at the opening part. I don't see anything opening. What did i do wrong on windows?

Comment: On windows, are you using Visual Studio ? If it is the case, you have to make sure you are building a console  application.

If you add `std::cout<<"Hello"<<std::endl;` at the beginning of the program, do you see the text displayed in the console ?

Comment: I use code blocks for any C and C++ programs. I always work on console applications and use the GNU compiler to see output and see how the program is behaving. While searching for a solution i didn't seem to find anything that related to your std out method with code blocks. Most of the time its just written the way i have and it works. Am i perhaps missing something on code blocks that i should have included.

Answer (score 0):

Your file should be at correct path if your project name is suppose project_name so keep the file at /project_name/project_name/assignmentG1.txt .
Assuming you are using visual studio.

Comment: i figured it out. yes the method i used was for macs. Im using windows. I had to use the entire C path plus second backslash for each folder in the path. Its really complicated but it worked. it looks something more like this inputFile.open("C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\WebPage Portfolio Folder\\file2.txt");

Comment: If it is correct then please mark it as correct answer.